# WebDriverWait not available in openQA.Selenium.Support.UI

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, package, nuget-package

Take a look at the screenshot below. I have tried removing and reinstalling Selenium-support package. I am using Visual Studio 2013. Because of this I am not able to use it in my class.
Selenium and Selenium-Support versions are `3.6.0`

[image]

How do I get this fixed? I have searched for this online but most of the question did not use the selenium-support package, but here its not the case.

Answer (score -1):

---

I have already solved, that's try to manually downgrade the version of selenium support.
In case you need it. I wrote here.
1. remove all the selenium package from nuget.
2. open tools->library package manager->package manager console.
3. type Install-Package Selenium.Support -Version 3.5.1
This version is good, I can use WebDriverWait now.

Comment: You should not need to downgrade. You might need to remove and readd the package references, but a downgrade should never be required.

Answer (score -1):

The `WebDriverWait` class has been moved into the main WebDriver assembly. To use `WebDriverWait`, you no longer need the support package. The namespace remained the same, so for the vast majority of users, this change was entirely transparent, since most projects that reference `WebDriver.Support` also reference `WebDriver`.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure the reason for the downvote. The answer is entirely accurate. I suppose one could take issue with the decision to move the class, but that’s not material to this answer.